# How can I allow users to download pictures (.gif,.png,.jpeg)?

Tags: php, javascript, image, file, download

How can I allow users to download pictures saved on the server? The goal is to have the user click on a link and have a specified image to start to download.

Facebook example:
[image: image download]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the link to another .php page, not the image. Then on that page use the content-disposition header like this:

```
<?php
// Define the name of image after downloaded  
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.jpg"');  

// Read the original image file  
readfile('file.jpg');  
?>
```

From there, you can just add the filename of the image in a get command like

```
`download.php?filename=file`
```

then reference that in the file as:

```
readfile($_GET['filename'].'.jpg')
```

Comment: Good answer, but please **always sanitize `$_GET` before passing to something like `readfile`** (the above would allow me to download any file on your server ending ".jpg", and probably others with a bit of work). Maybe you knew this but omitted it for brevity, but others might take your example literally and introduce a big security hole into their server.

Comment: Very true IMSoP. I questioned whether or not to even include the part about making the php file dynamic in this way because I knew I didn't want to take the space to mention the security concerns.

Comment: How can I determine which of the three file extensions the image is?

Comment: Pete, this is worth it's own Question, but since you asked here, use exif_imagetype(), as in exif_imagetype(image.gif) == IMAGETYPE_GIF. Documentation is at http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php

Answer (score 2):

You need to set a specific header on the response that delivers the image in order to force a download.

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myawesomefilename.png
```

Otherwise it will just load up in browser.

So send that header and then just link to the path that delivers that image with that header.

Answer (score 1):

Send a header to tell the browser to download it like this:

```
header("Content-type: application/force-download")
```

Then send them the data for the file itself without any HTML or anything.

This example is snipped from the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

```
<?php
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: There is no media type named `application/force-download`.

Answer (score 1):

If by "download pictures saved on the server" you mean "try to make the browser offer a 'save as' dialog box instead of just displaying the image" then you might want to look into using the [Content-Disposition: attachment](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1) header in the response that serves the image:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="thefilename.jpg"
```

You can set headers in php using the [header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).