# Allow users to download ONLY images

Tags: php

I have written a script and just stored them in localhost.
I just want to know how can i allow users only to download the images.

I mean, if there is a hole in the script, people can download any files from the server.
I was searching here for some scripts with high security. So users can't download anything apart from images.

I found something here.
[How can I allow users to download pictures (.gif,.png,.jpeg)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046334/how-can-i-allow-users-to-download-pictures-gif-png-jpeg)

Is it really safe?

Comment: Not that raw `$_GET` value. Whitelist paths, check with `realpath()`...

Comment: You can do all of this with Apache, no need for PHP.

Comment: You can place your script files outside server's access and allow it handle only images. *.php files would be handled by the PHP.

Comment: download.php?file=image_file -- instead of this, if they try to run download.php?file=index.php what will happen? how to avoid such a things?

Answer (score 0):

the way i have done this is to set up the hierachy in a certain way.

MAIN FOLDER

- Index (server root)

  - Index.php
  - Pictures (folder)
- Pages
- Files

This means the files and pages are above the server root file so the user can not access them (unless you write a script which gives then the files). you can move pictures to outside the server root however you **WILL** have to write a script to fetch the images from outside the root as otherwise the server does not like it when fetching images.

Comment: This structure is useful when we allow users to upload. So they can't upload executable files in the document root. I want to let them download and at the same time, they should not get any chance to download the scripts.